# Passing array value from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, laravel

Note: using the Laravel framework but the concept shouldn't be too different.

How would I go about passing my `$data['method']` and `$data['id]` to javascript?

```
<div id="player" data-method="{{ $data['method'] }}" data-id="{{ $data['id'] }}"></div>
```

Data method and Data id are passed through a controller.

In javascript I've currently got

```
var method = "<?php echo $data-id[]>";
var id = "<?php echo $data-method[]>";
```

Which obviously don't work

Comment: Why `echo $data-method[]`? The `[]` is normally used to push data to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the method:

```
var method = document.getElementById("player").getAttribute("data-method");
```

And to get the id:

```
var id = document.getElementById("player").getAttribute("data-id");
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @chris97ong answer, if you use jQuery, then you can use such constructions:

```
var method = $('#player').data('method');
var id = $('#player').data('id');
```

But if you want to paste id and method values directly to javascript, then use:

```
var method = "<?php echo $data['id']>";
var id = "<?php echo $data['method']>";
```

Exactly like in your own way.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array as

```
<?php
    $array = array("a","b","c","d");
    $json_str = json_encode($array);
?>
<a str='<?php echo $json_str; ?>' class="array_pass">Pass Value</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".array_pass").click(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("str");
        var array = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
        alert(array[0]);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey Way provides a nice plugin to pass variables to JavaScript in your controller: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer